# Pytorch automatically update my python after installed

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, conda

I getting started with python, I installed pytorch on my new conda environment, but it update my python version from 3.9.13 to 3.10.6. I want to maintain the 3.9.13 version. is any thing I can do?

i had try

```
conda install python=3.9.13
```

but its failed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Recreate the environment, specifying the Python version at creation time.

```bash
conda env remove -n foo
conda create -n foo -c pytorch python=3.9.13 pytorch
```

Note that Conda does not share Python across different environments, so this specification is arbitrary.